# Upgrade Omnibus GitLab with additional bundled libraries

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

We’ve inherited a GitLab instance of 8.15.5 and we’d like to upgrade. I think the initial install was with an Omnibus Package install although I’m not 100% sure. I’m just noticing now that there’s a gitlab-manifest file in /op/gitlab describing all the different bundled libraries that are in this GitLab instance. There may be additional libraries and possible internal tools installed in addition to the out-of-the-box GitLab v8.15.5.

Question is, if I want to upgrade, what would I need to do if I want to upgrade to, say, version 8.17.x ? Do I maybe test, and install v8.15.5 on a test machine to find out what libraries are there (in the gitlab-manifest) which come out of the box in the Omnibus 8.15.5 GitLab package and then check the differences between the two instances - the one in production and the one on my test machine. And then would I just install the missing libraries before upgrading ?